# Programmatic merging in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

Using pandas for regression.

Sample data:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
data = {'date': ['2014-05-01', '2014-05-02', '2014-05-03', '2014-05-04', '2014-05-05', '2014-05-06', '2014-05-07', '2014-05-08', '2014-05-09', '2014-05-10','2014-05-11', '2014-05-12', '2014-05-13', '2014-05-14', '2014-05-15', '2014-05-16', '2014-05-17', '2014-05-18', '2014-05-19', '2014-05-20'], 
    'height_in_cm': [134, 135, 135, 137, 138, 140, 140, 141, 142, 143, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 150, 151], 'participant_id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['date', 'height_in_cm', 'participant_id'])
```

So, we have multiple participants and height is measured everyday throughout the year. Sub-part of study is to find growth in height in different months of the year. So, we need to take height at first day of the month and combine it with data at the beginning for 3 other weeks. So, output for data shown above should be as shown below. How can Such merging be done in Pandas... Any leads?

```
data_required = {'ini_date': ['2014-05-01','2014-05-01'], 
    'height_in_cm': [134, 134], 'participant_id': [1,1], 'future_date': ['2014-05-08','2014-05-15'],'future_height': [141, 147], 'week': [2, 3]}

new_df = pd.DataFrame(data_required, columns = ['ini_date', 'height_in_cm', 'participant_id','future_date','future_height', 'week'])
```

Comment: If you can ensure each dataframe has a single participant (`pd.groupby`), I'd start by converting the dates from string to actual time objects (`pd.to_datetime`) and then making this the dataframe index. This will let you easily grab rows starting at the first of the month and use time arithmetic to add one, two, three weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial starting point would be to convert the date to DateTime and change the freq. to weekly.

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.date))
df = df.asfreq('W-THU') #This corresponds to your first day of the week

df['Week'] = df.index.week - df.index[0].week
df = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0]).transpose().reset_index().merge(df.iloc[1:], on='participant_id', suffixes=('', '_future'))

del df['index']; del df['Week'] #Removing redundant columns
```

**Update**

The thing about your question is that you use the first day of the month as a starting point and then shifts that by a 7D/14D period, all done in time stamps not in Periods.

```
import pandas as pd

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df['y-m'] = df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m') #To make sure you track growth month to month
MonthStart = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', freq='MS', periods=100) #Generation for the first day of the month

mask = df.date.isin(MonthStart.shift(1, '7D')) | df.date.isin(MonthStart.shift(2, '7D'))
df[df.date.isin(MonthStart)].merge(df[mask], on=['participant_id', 'y-m'], suffixes=('', '_future')).drop('y-m', axis=1)
```

**Explanation**

- You generate a list for the first day of the month
- You create a shift for 1 and 2 weeks
- You filter the month start and merge it with the shifts
- Preferably throw in the month identifier in the equation so that you don't match events in April with June for example.

**Output**

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>height_in_cm</th>
      <th>participant_id</th>
      <th>date_future</th>
      <th>height_in_cm_future</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>2014-05-01</td>
      <td>134</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2014-05-08</td>
      <td>141</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>2014-05-01</td>
      <td>134</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2014-05-15</td>
      <td>147</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This assumes that Thursday would be first day of the month. But, as I wrote, we have data for 1 year so, for each month starting day would be different. Anyways, Thanks.

Comment: @XingfangLee I updated my answer accordingly, please check it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the help.